# How to create a valid Privacy policy URL for facebook app..?

Tags: android, facebook-apps, privacy-policy, facebook-app-settings

in latest facebook for developers site in order to LIVE your app for all users you have to add Privacy
policy URL into Settings of that app.

i follow these steps:

1. go to termsfeed.com
2. entered all details and generate a Link provided by that website.
3. i paste that URL into Settings inside Privacy Policy URL it gives me **URL Broken error**

i got some this kind of missing fields and dialog

[image]

above image is the output when i put this URL into **Facebook Sharing Debugger Tool**

Please tell me how i can add Privacy policy URL in order to Live my app login for all users,otherwise untill when i will give permissions to access into my app

Comment: Maybe you've copied the wrong URL?

Answer (score 0):

The errors are not related to a Privacy Policy URL of a Facebook app but from a specific tool called "Facebook Sharing Debugger Tool" that can be used to test out if a certain URL has the necessary `og` tags.

The errors inform you that the page URL does not have the `og` tags: https://ogp.me/

[image]

Comment: Then how i can do that.? Please help

Comment: If you give the steps for how to create privacy policy URL for the app it would be better

Comment: What's the Privacy Policy URL that you've tried to add to Facebook?

Comment: i created a website demotaskapp.000webhostapp.com where i put index.html in which i paste all privacy text and publish it but again facebook sharing debugger showing The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags

Comment: Try to add it as https://demotaskapp.000webhostapp.com/ (with the http or https protocol) and see if it works.

Comment: No sir it is not working it is asking for same og properties as i mentioned in above question

Comment: Create an image in your root folder and add the tag to your `index.html`: `<meta property="og:image" content="demotaskapp.000webhostapp.com/image.png" />`

Comment: And what about other og tags title,url,type, description, and fb:app_id

Comment: Add them as well. They are descriptive enough: title is title of page, description is a description.